# vote number on trello cards

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I have a trello card which has only one member, but a vote count of 1/2. It would make some sense if there are two members, and only one voted. However, this can't be the case given there is only one member.

What does the 2 in the denominator mean if not members?

---

I think I got confused. what I wanted to ask is why I am getting "2 votes (with you)".

does it mean I voted twice somehow? I can't seem to get it to say 1 vote by cancelling the vote. It is always 2 or nothing.

and what does (with you) mean?

Answer (score 3):

You have a checklist on that card with one of two items completed.

Comment: a checklist is a completely different thing from votes. why mix them up?

Comment: That's true; I'm not sure why you mixed them up.  Is the icon ambiguous?  I believe it'll say "n votes" if there are votes on a card.

Comment: I think I got confused. what I wanted to ask is why I am getting "2 votes (with you)".

does it mean I voted twice somehow? I can't seem to get it to say 1 vote by cancelling the vote. It is always 2 or nothing.

and what does (with you) mean?